# How to dynamically initialize a variable

Tags: matlab, dynamic, eval

I want in matlab dynamically initialize a variable. I need that because I want the user to define arbitary much constants and a formula that calculates that. Also, I want to have a slider to adjust the constants so they can't be given just in the formula. I have a formula, that is applied on the formula of the user and of the result I have a differential equation which I want to solve. I have a working program but it's very slow.

I tried to give the constants to the function that is put inside the differential equation and that works. However, I guess because evaluation of "eval" is very slow and a function inside a differential equation is called very often, that a lot of time is wasted by redefining the constants

smallest code not working

```matlab
function test1
    eval("x = 0;");
    function test2
    end
end
```

I expect that x is dynamically created and useable inside test2.

Comment: The problem with your design is that the user could define a variable with a name that matches one of the variables in your own code, breaking your program. Dynamic variables are a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [assignin](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.htm) by creating a variable in `test2` and assign it to `test1` (non-nested function).

Example from Matlab's help:

```
function m = minRand2(n)
    assignfh2(n)

    A = fh(n)
    m = min(A(:));
end

function assignfh2(n)
    rand = 13*ones(n);
    fh = @(dim)rand(dim);
    assignin('caller','fh',fh)
end
```

then call

```
m = minRand2(2)
```

Example with the naming convention proposed in the question:

```
test1 

function m = test1
    test2
    disp(name_var_a);
end

function test2
    eval(['value_a = "I am a string";']);
    assignin('caller','name_var_a', value_a)
end
```

Calling `test1` gives:

```
I am a string
```

You can use `evalin` too.

Comment: First, thanks for the fast response. Unfortunately it's not working. Or I didn't understood what you're trying to say me. At least, when I have a nested function in minRand2, it's not working and it's exactly what I need. Because I need to overcome somehow the evaluation of e.g. "C=0"

Comment: I edited the answer. It is just an example of how one can use eval / assignin in functions. There are other designs possible.

Comment: The provided codes work, but not the following code, that I need:

Comment: sorry can't post it. a nested function inside the minRand2 / test1